# How to access an Object's values using arr.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to achieve the below:

```
var arr = [
 {name: 'width', value: 10}, 
 {name: 'height', value: 20}, 
]

arr.reduce((ack, item)=>{
  ack.width = item.value
  ack.height = item.value
  return ack
},{})

//Expected output:

{width: 10, height: 20}

//Actual output:

{width: 20, height: 20}
```

Maybe I don't understand how `.reduce()` works a 100%?

Comment: Your function overwrites the width **and** the height with the value for each item in the array in turn. If you want to do it conditionally based on the `item.name` then you have to pay attention to the `item.name`!

Comment: This is an abuse of `reduce`. I wish people would stop using `reduce`, its really not that cool: https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224?lang=en

Comment: @morganney. I am practicing this exercise because I failed at it in a coding interview a couple days ago. I agree with you and the post on Twitter that this approach is harder to read than other approaches specially for a Jr Dev like myself. I also wish people would stop using `reduce` this way, specially during interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` method executes a  callback function on each element of the array, so in your issue, on every iteration you have an object that contains `name` and `value` property. you can achieve your goal like this:

```js
let arr = [
 {name: 'width', value: 10}, 
 {name: 'height', value: 20}, 
]

let result = arr.reduce((ack, item)=>{
  ack[item.name] = item.value
  return ack
},{})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I don't understand how .reduce() works a 100%?

Appears so. Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Every time the `reducer` function is called - `ack` is what was returned **last time from the reducer** (or the initial value if it's the first pass) and item is the current item.

It helps to do this:

```
arr.reduce((ack, item)=>{
  console.log(ack); // this will help you understand
  ack[item.name] = ack[item.value]
  return ack
},{})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `name` as key.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'width', value: 10 }, { name: 'height', value: 20 }],
    result = array.reduce(
        (object, { name, value }) => ({ ...object, [name]: value }),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```